# How to install PHP extension 'pcntl' on my Mac OSX

Tags: php, phabricator, pcntl

My operating system is:Mac OSX 10.11

I'm trying to install Phabricator on my Mac, when I execute the command of

```
phabricator cpopt$ ./bin/phd start
```

I got an error:

```
"ERROR: The PHP extension 'pcntl' is not installed. You must install it to run daemons on this machine."
```

I've search this problem on google and I got lots of solutions,but they all don't work to me,I'm almost in despair.

How can I achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you have brew installed (read here to install http://brew.sh/)?

Try:

```
brew install php
```

or if you need to install PHP 5.6 with brew you could do this:

```
brew install php@5.6
```

Then to include it in your PATH (if it is not automatically added), it may be necessary to  run the commands in the CLI you may need to update your path, e.g. (this is the case if you were to `brew install php@7.1` but was not the case when I just tested with `brew install php` - if you are using bash instead of zsh, change .zshrc to .bashrc.

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.1/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

If that doesn't work, I wonder if phabricator is calling the right version of php.

Out of curiosity, what is the output you get from this?  That is what phabricator is using to determine your php version.

```
/usr/bin/env php -v
```

Also... is your php.ini updated to have the pcntl extension?  Run this to see your modules and look for pcntl:

```
php -i | grep pcntl
```

Double-check the php.ini that the php-cli is running:

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

Comment: According to your method, I install the homebrew and execute the command 'brew install homebrew/php/php55-pcntl ', It's works to me.Thank you very much,you save my time.Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: also, brew is a package management tool so you'll likely use it to install many things on the future on OSX too!

Comment: OK,I got it, Thank you

Comment: @ClaytonSmith please if you could help me to install these php extensions...i have brew and php7 on MAC but i can't install these: OpenSSL PHP Extension
PDO PHP Extension 
Mbstring PHP Extension
Tokenizer PHP Extension
XML PHP Extension    i can't find the command

Comment: I am getting this error Error: No available formula with the name "homebrew/php/php55-pcntl"  on all

Comment: @MuhammadUmar I've updated the answer, feel to upvote if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this to install the platform.sh command line tool. This was the top hit in Google so I'm adding this information. The process I followed was as below.

In Terminal:

Add yourself to the 'wheel' user group.

```
sudo dscl . append /Groups/wheel GroupMembership <username>
```

Grant group write access to /usr/local/bin

```
sudo chmod -R g+w /usr/local/bin
```

Link libpng for brew

```
brew link libpng
```

Install pcntl for php (5.6 in my case)

```
brew install homebrew/php/php56-pcntl
```

Comment: Error: homebrew/php was deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else uses MAMP, I recently updated it to the latest version. Then I was getting the error

`"ERROR: The PHP extension 'pcntl' is not installed. You must install it to run daemons on this machine."`

I had not restarted my terminal since I updated it. After reloading the session everything worked fine.